# ASP.NET CheckBox does not fire CheckedChanged event when unchecking

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I have a CheckBox on an ASP.NET Content Form like so:

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkTest" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkTest_CheckedChanged" />
```

In my code behind I have the following method:

```
protected void chkTest_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

When I load the page in the browser and click the CheckBox it becomes checked, the page posts back, and I can see `chkTest_CheckedChanged` being called.

When I then click the CheckBox again it becomes unchecked, the page posts back, however `chkTest_CheckedChanged` is not called.

The process is repeatable, so once the CheckBox is unchecked, checking it will fire the event.

I have View State disabled in the Web.Config, enabling View State causes this issue to disappear. What can I do to have reliable event firing while the View State remains disabled?

**Update:**
If I set `Checked="true"` on the server tag the situation becomes reversed with the event firing when un-checking the CheckBox, but not the other way around.

**Update 2:**
I've overridden `OnLoadComplete` in my page and from within there I can confirm that `Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"]` is set correctly to the ID of my CheckBox.

Comment: that happens to me too, why does it happen? any info? any light at the end of this tunnel (that isnt gonna run me over)?

Comment: it will help if you can post the code of your Page_Load event

Comment: There is nothing in the Page_Load event. All the code is in the original post.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Implementing a custom CheckBox that stores the `Checked` property in `ControlState` rather than `ViewState` will probably solve that problem, even if the check box has `AutoPostBack=false`

Unlike ViewState, ControlState cannot be disabled and can be used to store data that is essential to the control's behavior.

I don't have a visual studio environnement right now to test, but that should looks like this:

```
public class MyCheckBox : CheckBox
{
    private bool _checked;

    public override bool Checked { get { return _checked; } set { _checked = value; } }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        //You must tell the page that you use ControlState.
        Page.RegisterRequiresControlState(this);
    }

    protected override object SaveControlState()
    {
        //You save the base's control state, and add your property.
        object obj = base.SaveControlState();

        return new Pair (obj, _checked);
    }

    protected override void LoadControlState(object state)
    {
        if (state != null)
        {
            //Take the property back.
            Pair p = state as Pair;
            if (p != null)
            {
                base.LoadControlState(p.First);
                _checked = (bool)p.Second;
            }
            else
            {
                base.LoadControlState(state);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1whwt1k7.aspx#Y342).

Comment: Thanks this works like magic.  I can't believe in all the time I've been working in .Net I've never run into this issue until now.  This also works on Dynamically created Checkboxes, just register them as "MyCheckBox" instances instead of the standard ones and your good to go.

Comment: Big up - thanks. Why checkboxes can't work out of the box I don't know.

Answer (score 33):

To fire CheckedChanged event set the following properties for CheckBox, AutoPostBack property should be true and should have a default value either checked false or true.

```
AutoPostBack="true" Checked="false"
```

Comment: The accepted answer is an overkill for this simple problem. This answer should've been the accepted answer.

Comment: I can't agree more with @MatheusRocha. I was very discouraged with the accepted answer and was surely not going to try it. This answer is really saved me from changing my design.

Comment: Good man! I agree this should be the accepted answer. Certainly worked for me!

Comment: This needs to be the accepted answer for this situation.

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't fire because with viewstate disabled the server code does not know that the checkbox was previously checked, therefore it doesn't know the state changed.  As far as asp.net knows the checkbox control was unchecked before the postback and is still unchecked.  This also explains the reverse behavior you see when setting `Checked="true"`.

Comment: I'm coming back to this after a year, so I can't remember exactly what my thoughts were back then, but you're right, the page lifecycle does cause this effect. I think possibly I was expecting that because the __EVENTTARGET was set to my checkbox that ASP.NET might be clever enough to realise it had changed.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure but I guess that my solution is working only for .NET Framework 4.0:

Use `ViewStateMode = "Disabled"` to disable view state insted of `EnableViewState="false"`. This will caution the same behavior except that you can save a local view state.

So, on your checkbox, set the attribute `ViewStateMode = "Enabled"` and the problem is solved, without implementing a custom checkbox.

Answer (score 6):

It's an old post but I had to share my simple solution in order to help others who searched for this problem.

The solution is simple: **Turn on AutoPostBack.**

```
        <asp:CheckBox id="checkbox1" runat="server"
                AutoPostBack="True" //<<<<------
                Text="checkbox"
                OnCheckedChanged="knowJobCBOX_CheckedChanged"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to tidy things up a bit so I've just spent a bit of time testing a solution for this.

joshb is correct with his explanation for why the CheckBox behaves the way it does.

As I don't know how I got round this last year or even if I did (I can't remember what I was working on at the time to check), I've put together a simple solution/workaround.

```
public class CheckBox2 : CheckBox
{
    protected override bool LoadPostData(string postDataKey, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection postCollection)
    {
        bool isEventTarget = postCollection["__EVENTTARGET"] == UniqueID;
        bool hasChanged = base.LoadPostData(postDataKey, postCollection);
        hasChanged = hasChanged || isEventTarget;
        return hasChanged;
    }
}
```

If you now register CheckBox2 in your page and use it in place of your standard CheckBoxes, you will get the CheckedChanged event fired as you expect with ViewState disabled and AutoPostBack enabled.

The way this works is allowing the normal CheckBox to do its thing with validation and change checking, but then performs an additional check to see if it was the target of the event that caused the postback. If it was the target, it returns true to tell the framework to raise the CheckedChanged event.

**Edit:**
Please note that this only solves the problem for AutoPostBack on the CheckBox. If the PostBack is invoked from anything else (a button, for example), the CheckedChanged event still exhibits the observed problem.

Comment: Might be helpful for case when LoadPostData is not calling http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211200/asp-net-custom-control-when-is-loadpostdata-called

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I have spent a lot of time on it and finally have solved it.

In my case the `Checkbox` was disabled by default:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" runat="server" Enabled="false"/>
```

It turns `ViewState` isn't loaded for disabled or invisible controls.
So remove `Enabled="false"` or `Visible="false"` and it will work as expeceted. And of course `ViewState` shouldn't be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally: **Check for any errors in the JavaScript console**.

I experienced the same exact issue described by OP except that it only happened in Safari (`checkbox` worked fine in Chrome and Firefox). Upon inspecting the JavaScript console, I found an error that was being thrown by a malformed `jQuery` selector.

In my case, I had `$('a[id*=lbView')` which was missing a closing `]`. This threw an error in Safari but, surprisingly, not in Chrome nor in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

The super easy answer is to set the `ViewState` on for that one control.

Just add the `EnableViewState="true"` to the `AutoPostBack="true"` property in the checkbox tag.

Answer (score 0):

The default value of "Checked" Property of CheckBox is `false` (which means Uncheck). So, when you Check/Uncheck the CheckBox it compares with Checked Property.

- If it does not match with Checked Property, ASP fires `OnCheckedChanged` Event.
- If it matches with the Checked Property it will not fire the `OnCheckedChanged` Event.

So, in order to make ASP to fire `OnCheckedChanged` event when unchecking, it has to know Original value, so that it compares with the value from user and fires the event.

By adding `data-originalValue='<%# Eval("ValueFromCodeBehind") %>'` property in `asp:CheckBox` will be able to fire the `OnCheckChanged` Event as ASP can now able to know its previous value. So that when we change it, ASP fires `OnCheckChanged` Event even if we do Uncheck.