# Radio Group doesn't unHide when Checkbox is selected

Tags: html, vb.net, checkbox, visible

I am trying to unhide a group of radio buttons if the checkbox above it is checked and hide them when checkbox isn't checked. I had a previous version of this, in the same application, and it works just fine [radio button opens checkboxes instead] under Working one. When `MinorCheck` is selected the radio buttons don't become visible. No errors show, nothing happens. Why is this?

I have looked at other comments how Visible = "false" stops it and so forth. however, it is clear that visible="false" at the start isn't an issue for my first block of coding.

one reference I have used: [ASP.NET CheckBox does not fire CheckedChanged event when unchecking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457136/asp-net-checkbox-does-not-fire-checkedchanged-event-when-unchecking)

**Working one:**

HTML

```
<td class="LeftAlign" width="24%">                 

<font class="Blackfont" size="1">
<B>                                     Union Affiliated?
</B>
</font>
<font class="WeOrangefont" size="1">
&#8226;
</font>
</td>
    <td width="10%">
       <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblclass" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" class="Bluefont" size="1" font-Bold="True" font-Size="8pt" >

              <asp:ListItem Value="Y">Yes</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem Value="N">No</asp:ListItem>
       </asp:RadioButtonList>
     </td>

     <td></td>  
  </tr>
</table>
```

VB.NET

```
Protected Sub rblclass_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rblclass.SelectedIndexChanged
    If (rblclass.SelectedValue = "Y") Then
        Register.Focus()
        union1.Visible = True
        union2.Visible = True
        union3.Visible = True
        LocalLbl.Visible = True
        Reqimage.Visible = True
    Else
        Register.Focus()
        union1.Visible = False
        union2.Visible = False
        union3.Visible = False
        LocalLbl.Visible = False
        Reqimage.Visible = False
    End If

End Sub
```

**Other part of coding that doesn't work even though it is very similar:**

```
<tr>
<td class="LeftAlign" colspan="2">
    <font class="Blackfont" size="1">
               <asp:CheckBox ID="MinorCheck" runat="server" NAME="BUSINESSCLASSIFICATION" 
               class="ownerClass" value="000" checked = "false" TabIndex="32"/>

               <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" TABSTOP = "-1" onClick="OpenWindow('Images/Supp.html', 'Min Business Concern',600, 300, 'no')" font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#666666" >Minority Business Concern</asp:HyperLink> 
   </font>
</td>

</tr>
<tr>    
  <td>
     <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonBClass" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
                            class="Bluefont" size="1" font-Bold="True" font-Size="8pt" visible = "false">

      <asp:ListItem Value="Y" >African-American male</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="N">African-American female</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="N">Asian-Indian American male</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="N">Asian-Indian American female</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="N">Asian-Pacific American male</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="N">Asian-Pacific American female</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="N">Native American male</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="N">Native American female</asp:ListItem>

  </asp:RadioButtonList>
  </td>
</tr>
```

VB.NET

```
Protected Sub MinorCheck_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MinorCheck.CheckedChanged
    If (MinorCheck.Checked = true) Then
        RadioButtonBClass.Visible = True
        NonMinorCheck.Checked = false
    Else
        RadioButtonBClass.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: when I posted I had "" over true/false for `MinorCheck` even though my coding didn't have it. Anyways, the above coding doesn't work as of right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your checkbox is missing the `AutotPostBack=True`.  Without it, the `CheckedChanged` event will not fire until some other control performs a `PostBack`.

Comment: I small mistake indeed. I officially understand now what AutoPostBack means o.o . I just always saw it and assumed it was required but now I know what happens when you don't have it. Thanks! this fixed my issue!!

Comment: if you don't mind me asking you a quick question... the first 2 radio buttons when selected work; however if the others happen to be chosen they change to the second radio button after the page "refreshes" to the top of the page after a radio button is checked @InbetweenWeekends

Comment: nevermind.. removed the value="n" and value="y" to stop that

Answer (score 1):

It is confusing but when you use the property Visible in ASP controls, actually don't create the object at all, so if you tried to change to Visible true is not going to work, what I personally use is a trick with a CSS Class, I am going to copy the code I made for your case:

```
<style>
    .CSSHiden {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

Note: I set Autopostback=true on the Checkbox Minor Check

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="MinorCheck" runat="server" NAME="BUSINESSCLASSIFICATION" 
           class="ownerClass" value="000" TabIndex="32" OnCheckedChanged="MinorCheck_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="True"/>
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" TABSTOP = "-1" onClick="OpenWindow('Images/Supp.html', 'Min Business Concern',600, 300, 'no')" font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#666666" >Minority Business Concern</asp:HyperLink>

    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonBClass" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" class="Bluefont" size="1" font-Bold="True" font-Size="8pt" CssClass="CSSHiden">
        <asp:ListItem Value="Y" >African-American male</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="N">African-American female</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="N">Asian-Indian American male</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="N">Asian-Indian American female</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="N">Asian-Pacific American male</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="N">Asian-Pacific American female</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="N">Native American male</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="N">Native American female</asp:ListItem>

    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

And the code I used c#, but is very simple to change to VB.net

```
protected void MinorCheck_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MinorCheck.Checked == true)
            RadioButtonBClass.CssClass = "";
        else
            RadioButtonBClass.CssClass = "CSSHiden";
    }
```

Comment: @InbetweenWeekends fixed my issue. I have always used visible = "false" but didn't realize that it would mean the object wasn't created. I will look more into that concept for sure. I will also see into testing your example too. I appreciate the example you gave me. Never thought of pulling a class in an if else statement :)